# CSS vertical image positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a function to display images. It open hidden div, containing image and div with black overlay.

```css
.black-overlay {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
.white-content {
  z-index: 11;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 5%;
}
.white-content .main-image {
  z-index: 11;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #FFF;
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 90%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="black-overlay hide"></div>
<div class="white-content hide">
  <img class="main-image" src="//dummyimage.com/200" />
</div>
```

Horizontally image is aligned on the center, which is what I want.

The problem is, that vertically the image always stick to the top and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Can someone help me to solve it (I can add extra divs if it is needed)

Comment: Why not to combine two overlays into one?

Comment: And use rgba instead of opacity - [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/wcvyvg4v/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use display: flex for centering:

```
.white-content{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.white-content .main-image{
  display: block;
}
```

This will center the image both horizontally and vertically. Remember to add prefixes for older browsers.

Comment: now it do the vertical aligning, but it doesn't work on mobile devices and it doesn't keep resolution of the picture

Comment: What mobile browser doesn't work? And what exactly do you mean by 'not keeping resolution'? Can you post a screenshot maybe?

Comment: in mobile browser it still sticks to the top.
in desktop browser if I have an image of 900x600 and change my browser window to 500x500, the image will occupy entire 500x500 by deformation

Comment: Did you remove the max-width and max-height from the code you posted above? Which browser are you using on mobile? Chrome, safari, android default(old), opera or something else?